# Detect actual precision and scale for Oracle number data type

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, numbers

One of our Oracle data sources has hundreds of tables with all numeric columns defined using NUMBER data type without precision and scale. But in fact, a column can store pure integer values or decimal values - there is no way to tell that by looking at data type alone. Now, this is a big problem because when I try to load any of this data to Big Data tools (Sqoop, Hive, Spark etc.) all these tools treat these columns as strings and this is a super painful issue to deal with. I think it is an issue with all JDBC/Java based tools.

Is it possible to detect somehow the actual precision and scale of values stored in a column with NUMBER type. My hope Oracle keeps this somewhere in metadata tables but I do not see that anywhere. My last resort is to do a random sampling of data in a table and store conversion schema on a side but I hope there is a better way. I really do

For example a table `TEST` has three columns, `ID`, `AMOUNT` and `QUANTITY` all declared as a NUMBER with no precision or scale specified.

But in fact `ID` should be a bigint, `AMOUNT` should be decimal(18,6) and `QUANTITY` should be an int.

```
create table test (
ID number,
AMOUNT number,
QTY number
)

ID     AMOUNT    QTY
1      200.56    4
2      23.754    5
```

I cannot possibly do the mapping manually because I have 600 tables and each table has 50-300 columns. Data sampling is my last resort.

Comment: So your problem is that the tools you're using are treating numbers as strings rather than int/floats etc.? What exactly are you using to do the loading - [there's a type mapping that should be used](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/basic3.htm) which certainly doesn't put numbers in strings.

Comment: I don't get the problem. You have all NUMBERs in Oracle. But in Hive you want some of them INTEGER, some FLOATS, some SMALLINT, etc? You should know your data, or just sample/profile it before import....

Comment: here is example: tableA column ID has type NUMBER, column amount type NUMBER and column quantity type NUMBER - no precision or scale specified. But in fact ID should be bigint, amount should be decimal(18,6) and quantity should be int. I cannot possibly do the mapping manually because I have 600 tables and each table has 50-300 columns. Data sampling is my last resort as I've mentioned in my question

Comment: @Ben I am using sqoop and Hive and same issue with NiFi. Same issue with Kafka JDBC Connector - actually even worse because Kafka assigns decimal(38,0) datatype which is plane wrong. So I decided to load them as strings and then have a processing step to cast/map to a proper data type but I need to figure out how to assign proper data type and infer it from source Oracle schema

Comment: @FlorinGhita I wish I would know all the data in 600 tables and each having 50-300 columns :) but I am not that good

Comment: Can you give examples of actual data: what values are in the columns and what output (precision/scale) are you expecting to infer from those if the metadata hasn't been explicitly specified during table creation?

Comment: Sure, added an example with ddl and sample data.

Comment: Looking at that data alone, _how_ do you know that `AMOUNT` should be `DECIMAL(18,6)`? Nothing in the data implies that, so how do you know the scale is 6; do _you_ have the metadata somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I know because I did select * from a table and observed the data. I am thinking now that doing random data sampling and data type detection based on the actual data
is the only option here. I also checked Oracle statistics tables and no luck there as well. Could not derive that from stats histograms tables neither :-(

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334854/oracle-number-type-without-precision-how-do-i-know-if-it-is-a-whole-number-or) for a good solution (still pain but at least something)

Answer (score -1):

Oracle number types default to 38.0

Comment: it is not, it will use whatever precision / scale it needs to use to fit the actual number - see examples here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832

Answer (score -2):

To get the `SCALE` and `PRECISION` defined to a `NUMBER` column when it was created, you can query Oracle's data dictionary views `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, or `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` if all tables are under the same schema.

These views hold the information in columns `DATA_PRECISION` and                                    `DATA_SCALE`.

Comment: If no precision or scale is declared in the database this will return NULL for both. This is the OPs problem.

Comment: @Ben, so then you use `NVL(DATA_PRECISION, 38) as DATA_PRECISION, NVL(DATA_SCALE, 0) as DATA_SCALE` in the query. This will use the default values when precision/scale hasn't been defined in the DDL. Can you explain how my answer is incorrect, justifying a down-vote? OP explicitly asked for the metadata table that holds this information.

Comment: The OP asked for a method of determining what the data is, not what the metadata looks like. The OP is well aware of how to get the metadata.

Comment: Well..no, the question states "My question is it possible to detect somehow the actual precision and scale of values stored in a column with NUMBER type. My hope Oracle keeps this somewhere in metadata tables but I do not see that anywhere.". Which 1) isn't asking "what the data is" and 2) doesn't show that OP knows "how to get the metadata". If you think my answer is _incorrect_, please explain _how_. Or better, answer the question yourself.

Comment: I can't answer the question myself because I don't think there's a good answer. The reason why your answer is incorrect is in your quote. You've shown the way to get the declared precision and scale, not the actual data. Part of my proof is deleted. You're the third person to provide this answer and the OP has confirmed on those deleted answers that my interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: I have asked the OP in the comments, and I have to ask you again: what do you mean with "actual data"? I still don't see a justification for a DW, given the information provided in the question. Again, please tell me how to improve the answer -- or provide a better answer yourself.

Comment: I am aware of Oracle tables and columns metadata but as I explained in the question it does not work here because precision and scale set to null